# ASP.NET wrap an asp:HyperLink in <li>'s, from server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have the next structure for a menu item:

```
class MenuItem
{
    public string Path, Title;
}
```

I want to be able to Iterate an object of `MenuItem[]`, creating a new object of `asp:HyperLink` on each iteration, and to add it to a `<ul>` list.

One thing that must happen is that each HyperLink will be inside a `<li>` tag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a repeater. In the aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repMenuItems" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMenuItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Path")%>'/></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
repMenuItems.DataSource = arrMenuItem;  // your MenuItem array
repMenuItems.DataBind();
```

Additionaly you should change your class code for using Public Properties instead of Public Members, like this:

```
public class MenuItem 
{ 
    public string Title {get;set;} 
    public string Path {get;set;} 
}
```

I recommend you to read more about Properties in .NET, a nice feature for object encapsulation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope this helps you

Comment: Can do the same thing in a Listview if you need the more robust functionality of the Listview. Though if you dont then the repeater is lighterweight

Comment: @Agustin Meriles, thanks for your solution. Testing it gave me an Error: "DataBinding: 'NAMESPACE.MenuItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Title'.

Comment: I Believe that the problem is that Title is not a Property, but a Member. You should try using Properties insted of Members. Change you class code like this: `public class MenuItem { public string Title {get;set;} public string Path {get;set;} }`